# non sequitur, should be quick fix. why is y=2, (y==int() False)what did I miss:

Tags: python

I just typed this into IDLE shell.
maybe somethigns up with it? or it was a snake and it bit me ( as the saying goes)

the statement is:

```
y=2
y==int()
```

output:

```
false
```

I even tried:

```
y=23
type(y)
```

output:

```
<class 'int'>
```

input:

```
y==int()
```

output:

```
False
```

what am I missing?
hoping to learn something here

Answer (score 0):

Type in `print(int())` into your shell. It will print 0. Since `0 != 2`, `y != int()`.

You likely want either:

```
type(y) == int

type(y) is int
```

or

```
isinstance(y, int)
```

with the latter being better practice than the former, because it works with class inheritance (thanks to @dskrypa for his comment).

Note: From the documentation, if [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) is called without arguments, it will return 0. This is because `int()` is declared as:

```
class int(x=0)
```

Comment: It's best practice to use `isinstance(y, int)` and not `type(y) == int`.  If you're going to compare the `type(y)` value, the best practice is to use `is` instead of `==`, but that should be reserved for when it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: okay thyank you. my way results in incorrectness. why does your way work?--> do you know: how does "isinstance" work differently  than type() ? ... or if you can find the documentation for type() that would be great

Comment: `isinstance`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance ;  

`type()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Comment: @MarlonD.Alessandra did this answer your question, or is something still unclear?

Comment: yes, thank you... gave me a something to learn!